# Make Visual Studio run my own code that edits a solution item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

### Background

I'm using EntityFramework DB first and SQL server in my project. My tables have primary key columns with different names like PersonID, AccountID, AccountMemberID, etc. however, in my POCO classes, I wanted this to be represented as a property defined by an interface named just "ID" in all classes. In the designer, you can easily just rename the column on the entity, but this is tedious if you have 100+ tables to rename and also error-prone.

### Question

So I built a console app that reads an .edmx file and renames all of the primary key properties to "ID". What I want now is a way to make this easy to run from within Visual Studio. I could just include the console app in source control and then have the developer open the directory where it is and run it, but I'm trying to make it less easy to forget to run it. s there a way to kick it of from within Visual Studio? It would be easiest if it were to run every time the .edmx was saved, but I'd be happy with a few clicks within Visual Studio to run it. I don't know if this could be a custom tool, or a plugin, or extension, or command...can someone tell me where to get started?

**Edit**: I would also like it to be able to give feedback. Currently, as a console app, it prints out which entities were modified or any errors encountered. Also, it doesn't have to be a console app. I just want to keep my C# code if possible.

Comment: Do you have a T4 template file `*.tt` under your edmx file? Also what version of EF you are using?

Comment: Yes I do. EF 6.1.3

Comment: @AaronLS That's for CodeFirst OP is using DB First.

Comment: My mistake, there is both a "Code First Conventions" API and a "Model-Based Conventions", those articles mutually link to each other, and I assumed Model-Based referred to old style EDMX models, but that is incorrect.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make use of the Task Runner in Visual Studio. Take a look at the blog [Task runners in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/06/task-runners-in-visual-studio-2015/) (I know you said you are using 2015, but the feature is also in 2017).

I've done something similar where I had tasks written in [Cake Build](http://cakebuild.net/) generate SQL files from C# code. I then hooked up a before build task that generate new SQL files based on any changes the developer did to the C# code. This allowed us to validate a change very quickly before hitting commit and helped to reduce developer mistakes.

Comment: This is easy and gets it done! Thank you. I'm going to hold out for a little bit to see if there is a feasible solution that can run it when the file is saved before marking an answer.